Induction on the number of rows in linear algebras
This is my first question here. I am currently learning the operations to get the row echelon matrix. The textbook is Algebra by Michael Artin. It said that for any matrix, we can use elementary operation to get
\begin{align}
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c|ccc}
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & * & \cdots & * \\
\hline
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & * & \cdots & * \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & * & \cdots & * \\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align}
which we write as
$$\left[\begin{array}{c|c|c}
0&1 & B_1 \\
\hline
0 &0& D_1 \\
\end{array}\right]=M_1$$
Then, it said "We now perform row operations to simplify the smaller matrix $D_1$. Because the blocks to left of $D_1$ are zero, these operations will have no effect on the rest of the matrix $M_1$. By induction on the number of rows, we may assume that $D_1$ can be reduced to a row echelon matrix, say to $D_2$, and $M_1$ is thereby reduced to the matrix
$$\left[\begin{array}{c|c|c}
0&1 & B_1 \\
\hline
0 &0& D_2 \\
\end{array}\right]=M_2.$$
The entries in $B_1$ above the pivots of $D_2$ can be cleared out at this time, to finish the reduction to row echelon form."
What I cannot understant is the induction based on the number of rows. I know that mathematical induction is based on the natural numbers $\mathbf{N}$. However, it seems that here the induction is based on the number of rows, which is a finite number. Could you please help me with this question?

What's the difference between a natural number and a finite number, to you?

Thank you for your reply. In the mathematical induction, we validate the base case, assume the property for $n$, and then check if the property is true for $n+1$. The property is then true for all natural numbers $\mathbf{N}$. I am confused about how the author used induction here. The row reduction is used when the matrix is fixed. So the number of rows is upper bounded. I cannot find $n$ or $n+1$ in this case. This is why I do not know how to do induction on the number of rows.

You should check that the claim holds for matrices $D_1$ with 0 rows, then assume that it holds for matrices with $n$ rows and check that it holds for matrics with $n+1$ rows.
